# Check that initializers and finalizers are guaranteed to be logically paired in a block scope

Tags: c, static-analysis

Does there exist any automatic method or tool for analyzing C code to determine if all initializer function calls are logically paired with a corresponding finalizer function call in a block scope?

By initializer and finalizer I mean a pair like `fopen()` and `fclose()`.

---

**Significant editing to the original question took place:** The phrase "code path" was removed and the phrases "logically paired" and "in a block scope" were added in an attempt to clarify the original intent. See the extensive discussion under Eugene Sh.'s answer. By "logically paired" I'm contrasting with textually paired, e.g. it's unimportant whether there the source code text has equal numbers of initializer and finalizer calls. Instead, when a block scope is exited (if ever), any initializer function calls are guaranteed to have a corresponding finalizer function call.

*Examples*

Ok:

```
initialize();
mystery_function_that_may_never_return();
finalize();
```

Ok:

```
initialize();
if (cond)
   finalize();
else
   finalize();
```

Not ok:

```
initialize();
initialize();
finalize();
```

Not ok:

```
initialize();
finalize();
finalize();
```

Not ok:

```
initialize();
if (cond)
    finalize();
else
    return;
```

---

It could also make sense to transfer the finalization responsibility/transfer "ownership" of whatever resource is being managed so in that case the check would be that all initializations lead to either a finalization or ownership transfer.

Comment: This would require solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: They might not be in strict pairs. There might be one `fopen` and two alternative `fclose` of the same file, dependant on runtime conditions, or vice-versa. So would your hypothetical tool flag that? Although they are needed in pairs, there is no strict syntax pairing as is required for (brackets) and {braces}, "quotes" or /*comments*/.

Comment: For example, `void read_filehandle(FILE *fh) { ... if( done || feof(fh) ) { fclose(fh) } }` How do you account for that? This is a long winded way of saying "probably not".

Comment: @Schwern If you explain why that's the case, it would be a good answer. That said, an imperfect solution that sometimes can't determine if the calls are properly paired might still exist and could be useful.

Comment: @Praxeolitic perhaps it would need to be loose: a file was opened, was it ever closed? More difficult might be: memory was allocated, was it ever freed? In that case it might not be the same pointer that was freed, but a copy.

Comment: @Schwern In regards to that example, the answer I'd want there is that the calls are not paired on all possible code paths.

Comment: @WeatherVane Re: your first comment, the requirement would be pairs on all code paths, but not necessarily pairs in the text of the source code. It seems like this analysis is possible because it's similar to C++ destructors. Essentially wherever a C++ compiler would insert destructor calls, this tool should expect a finalizer call.

Comment: @Praxeolitic how many years will your logic analyser take to follow all possible paths of any but a trivial program?

Comment: @WeatherVane lol, I'm not looking to write this tool, I just want to know if there's an existing method to do this analysis. C++ compilers seem to have no trouble pairing constructors and destructors based on scoping so a few milliseconds I guess.

Answer (score 3):

## Probably Not.

Anything of the form "determine at compile time whether X happens at runtime" or "determine all code paths" in C runs into the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Maybe you can get away with it in a purely functional language like [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)).

For example...

```
bool find_thing( FILE *fp, const char* thing ) {
    ...go searching through the fp for thing...

    if( found_the_thing ) {
        fclose(fp);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        rewind(fp);
        return false;
    }
}

FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "r");
while( !find_thing(fp, that_thing) ) {
    ...mess with the file...
}
```

A bit contrived, it's off the top of my head, possibly more applicable to sockets. Point is once your initialier and finalizer aren't in linear sequence, once they get passed around, added to structs and arrays, maybe even assigned to a global, you run into trouble.

Here's another example.

```
typedef struct {
    FILE *fp;
    const char *filename;
} FileHandle;

FileHandle fh = malloc(sizeof(FileHandle));
fh->filename = file;
fh->fp = fopen(file, "r");

do_something(fh);

fclose(fh);
free(fh->filename);
free(fh);
```

Seems simple enough! Except how do you know that `fh->fp` contains the same file pointer as it was initialized with? What if `do_something` changed it? What if it already closed it? What if it opened a new one?

Here's yet another example.

```
FILE *fps[10];

...initialize fps...

/* Returns a file pointer from fps */
FILE *fp = highest_priority(fps);

...do something with fp...

fclose(fp);
```

What file pointer got closed?

As mentioned in the comments, this is perhaps easier to think about in terms of allocating and freeing memory, and that has the same problem. How do we know `fh->filename` hasn't been changed? What if it's NULL? What if it's already been freed? What if `fh` has already been freed?

A partial tool would give either only do the trivial cases, or it would give too many false positives or negatives, so as to be useless or so annoying you'd quickly turn it off.

If you're running into this problem a lot, consider switching to a style that handles all the IO operations for you in one tidy function. Pass it a function pointer of what to do with each line. For example, off the top of my head...

```
int read_file( const char* filename, void *thunk,
               void(*handle_line)(const char *, void *));
```

Best you could do is provide a runtime that lets you know if any resources were not finalized by the program's end, or finalized twice, or used while uninitialized. This is how most memory checkers in C work, such as [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind).

Comment: @Praxeolitic Same answer. The limitations you propose, requiring that all resources be initialized and finalized in the same scope, are so restrictive to make the whole exercise useless. How do you have functions which return initialized resources and attach them to larger structures?

Comment: An initializer could return an opaque pointer that hides arbitrary complexity which is cleanup up by the finalizer. For attaching objects there would need to be some convention for transferring ownership so maybe the condition should be revised to be either a finalizer is called or ownership is transferred for all initialized objects.

Comment: @Praxeolitic If your tool requires a very particular coding style and framework to meet the needs of the tool, that's putting the cart before the horse. You're basically proposing a major language modification.

Answer (score 2):

As @Schwern have mentioned, this problem is reducible to the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Consider an "initializer" function `Start()`, and the "finalizer" function `Stop()`.

Now to solve the halting problem for program `P()` it would be enough to run the proposed tool on the following program:

```
Start();
P();
Stop();
```

and check whether or not `Start()` is "paired" with `Stop()`.

More formally:

Assume there is a function `Paired(A)`, returning `true` if a there is a code path between the function `Start()` and `Stop()` (in case present in `A`) for any given input to a program. Then for any program `P()` we can construct a program `P'()`, such that
`P'()` is given by:

```
Start();
P();
Stop();
```

for which `Paired(P') = Halting(P)`. Hence having `Paired` we can solve `Halting` for any program `P`.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy into your example. I'd argue that `P` either halts and then it is paired or it doesn't halt and then the question is irrelevant. We want to know whether all resources are freed upon termination – a question that makes no sense for programs that never terminate.

Comment: Nice example, I see what Schwern is saying now, but in this case, regardless of what `P()` does, there's one code path as far as `Start()` and `Stop()` are concerned and they are paired on that code path.

Comment: @Praxeolitic They are not "paired" in case `P` is not halting, since there is no code path between them. If there was a code path between - it would halt (path means that it is followed).

Comment: @IngoBürk This is not an example, but an almost formal proof. And what you are saying is exactly the halting problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This seems like an issue of semantics. We want to guarantee that when the program halts (if ever), the functions will have been paired. If the program never halts then the condition is trivially satisfied.

Comment: @EugeneSh. And I like the concept of the proof. I'm questioning whether you are attempting to answer the right question. I think the question isn't whether `Stop` will always be called during runtime; it's whether all logical branches lead to a call to `Stop`.

Comment: … which is a question many static analyzers answer for different use-cases. Really it's the same question as whether all branches of a function lead to a `return` statement – something plenty of tools check at compile-time. Of course during runtime this doesn't mean much: you can have non-halting code paths etc. I just don't think we care about that here. The added complexity here is that a file handle can be passed between function calls. And of course pointers completely ruin any chance of proving runtime correctness anyway.

Comment: @IngoBürk If *all* of the logical branches are leading to "Stop", then it will get there in any case, thus halting. Is there a "code path" between two sides of an infinite loop (I mean before the loop and after the loop)? I wouldn't say that. Path is something that you can follow.

Comment: @IngoBürk Static analyzers are cool tools, but they are heuristical, and not analytical solvers. Which is nice in many cases, but not in all of them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. We all understand that a static check doesn't guarantee runtime correctness. This can be accepted. As I said, your answer is correct. It just answers a different question. We're not looking for guaranteed runtime correctness here.

Comment: @IngoBürk I think it is answering the question as it is stated. If you eliminate the "all code-paths" phrase from the question, it might change.

Comment: For the record, we don't need the halting problem to see that a compile-time check cannot guarantee runtime correctness. We just need to look at `file *f = open(); file *g = (file *)0x28ff44; close(g)`. Now it *could* just so happen that `0x28ff44` points to the location where `f` is stored. Or not. At compile time we simply cannot know.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I disagree. I think this very much depends on what you define as »code path«.

Comment: So.. My definition: A code path from instruction `A` to instruction `B` is a set of instructions starting from `A` and ending at `B` sequentially taken by a program. Note, that since it is ending by `B`, it must be finite. What is your definition?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Actually I do get your point now and agree with you. As you said, it's pure heuristics and thus the question was phrased in a misleading way.

Comment: The original intent of the "code path" phrasing was to distinguish logical pairing from textual pairing, e.g. `Start()` followed by an if/else where each branch ends in `Stop()` is ok even though the source text contains one `Start()` and twol `Stop()` calls. What phrasing would better express this? I didn't mean to raise the question of whether a "code path" must be finite.